# How to tile normal map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, normal-map

How can I tile normal map in Cycles?

I tried to use Texture Coordinates and Mapping nodes with different settings, it works with the texture, but doesn't work with the normal map.

[image]

Comment: I don't think tiling a normal map would be possible. Diffuse textures can be tiled, but normal maps are different, as they have bump and depth, which I don't think could be tiled.

Comment: Tiling a texture should be possible by scaling the incoming texture coordinates, regardless of the map type. Apart from that, you are using an Environment Image texture and the Color data options, while the usual setup requires an Image Texture whit Non Color data for normal maps. Try to fix those elements.

Comment: @Carlo Yes, It helped, thank you very much! If you will add this as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It is alredy tiled

Normal maps, like any other texture it's automatically tiled in cycles unless you are specifically clamping the tiling.

Scaling the incoming texture coordinates, should be enough to show up the repetition of the pettern regardless of the map type.

The problems from your setup comes from the usage of an Environment Image texture with Color data options, while the usual setup requires an Image Texture with Non Color data for normal maps.